# Передача данных из Android приложения в WCF-службу

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-studio, wcf, передача-данных

Делаю Android-приложение, которое будет обменивать данными с WCF-службой. И возник вопрос: каким образом ИЗ android-приложения передавать данные в wcf-службу? 
Из wcf в android данные я передаю посредством json, которая в android-е обрабатывается и из неё извлекаются данные. 
А как передавать данные обратно в службу не знаю. С помощью чего это можно реализовать на android, и как эти данные принимать и читать в wcf-службе?

Comment: А почему не хотите и обратно передавать данные ,как `JSON`?

Comment: @metalurgus, а так разве можно? Т.е. в андроиде генерируем json-строку, отправляем её в WCF-службу, и там парсим?

Comment: А почему нет? Если данные достаточно протые (просто несколько параметнов, без объектной структуры, и ненужно их десериализовывать), то пожно просто, как форму "ключ-значение" отправить. Все зависит от данных. Но `JSON`-объекты удобны тогда ,когда вы хотите передать сериализованные объекты.

Comment: @metalurgus, в принципе, данные простые - выбранные значения в combobox, записанные в textbox, дата в календаре и прочее(просто набор значений), которые в wcf службе будут обрабатываться и добавляться в базу данных. "Ключ-значение" - что подразумевается под этим?

Comment: Я имею в виду, как параметры POST запроса

Comment: @metalurgus, а можете на примере показать, как это саму передачу организовать? Вот создали мы json-строку, а как отправить её именно в нашу службу?